# PHP - Append text into html element with certain id

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a pre Element with id `output` and try to append multiple elements to it

```
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

Now in my PHP Code i run a for loop which simply outputs the counter variable (for the purpose of this example).

```
<?php
for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i = $i + 1)
{
  echo $i;
}
```

What is the best way to append these values to the pre element with id `output` by using PHP?

EDIT: I search for a solution which works if the for loop is not inside the pre tags. It should work no mather where in the code i call the for loop e.g. below the `<pre>` tags or above the `<pre>` tags, both should work.

Is this possible with PHP only?

Comment: you can append with `jquery` like `$('#output').append("<div></div>");`

Answer (score 3):

Since the php is rendered on page load, you don't need to append it - just have it in the div and echo it into output directly

```
<pre id="output">
<?php 
 $numbers=range (1,100);
    foreach ($numbers as $number) {
        echo "$number <br/>";
    }
 ?>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 2):

Not entirely sure if you want to use PHP to append stuff to it, or javascript. Considering your use of tags in this question

But for PHP you should do it at render time like this:

```
<?php

  $output = '';

  for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) {
    $output .= '<div>' . $i . '</div>';
  }  
?>

<pre id="output"><?=$output?></pre>
```

In javascript you can use `getElementById()`

```
var output = document.getElementById('output');
for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
   output.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
}
```

Comment: Thanks. yes this is possible, but i search for a solution which also works if the for loop is not inside the pre tags. Is this even possible with PHP only?

Comment: @EdwardBlack, then you have to generate JS script in PHP.

Comment: @EdwardBlack I've updated my answer. Do you mean something like this? It is still a bit vague what your actual problem is :)

Comment: Hi Edward - check out my second post - this has the php loop outside of the pre element as you request and appends the numbers into it. Note I have used jquery but is can also be done with straight javascript if you are not using jquery)

Comment: @PierreDuc, Thats a good solution and what i searched for, but unfortunattely this does not work if the <pre> Tags are above the PHP code. Otherwise you get `Undefined variable: output `. I think the only solution is to generate JS Script in PHP.

Comment: @EdwardBlack You could use a combination of `ob_start()` and `ob_get_clean()` to get the current output buffer. (and empty it). After that do a string replace or use `DOMDocument` to add data to the `pre` and output that result. But that might be pushing it ;).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version that does appends the numbers to the #output, with the php outside of that div as requested by the OP. Still happens at runtime, but this time creates a string and then appends it to the `<pre>` element as requested. I prefer the first one that I did though, with the php inside the element, unless there is a definitive reason for not using it, I would suggest hat one first.

```
<pre id="output"></pre> 
<?php 
 $numbers=range (1,100);
    $str="";
    foreach ($numbers as $number) {
        $str .= $number . "<br/>";
        }   
    echo "<script>$('#output').append('$str')</script>";
 ?>
```

Comment: Thats a good solution and what i searched for, but unfortunattely this does not work if the <pre> Tags are below the PHP code.

Comment: @EdwardBlack It does work if you let it execute the added script on document ready

Comment: I tried: `echo "<script> $(document).ready() { function() { $('#output').append('$str'); } }; </script>";` but it did not works either if the php code is called before the pre tag

Comment: I am assuming@PierreDuc meant something like this : leave the php at the top of the page and then in the js have: $(document).ready( function() { $('#output').append('<?php echo"$str";?>'); } ); which will work because the php $str is created at runtime and then on document.ready, will then be used in the append();

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>

<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <pre id="output">###MARK_PRE###</pre>
</body>
</html>

<?php

$html = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

$loop_result = "";

$arr = ['apple', 'orange', 'bananas'];

foreach($arr as $value)
{
  $loop_result .= "$value <br/>\n";
}

$html = trim(str_replace('###MARK_PRE###', $loop_result, $html));

echo $html;
```

This does the job. It works as you can see no matter if you place the for loop below or above your html.

If it is enough to have the loop above the html it gets much simpler. You should stick to the [answer of PierreDuc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35886859/5742575) in this case.

IF you really want to place the html above your php code, then you actually should better use a MVC-Framework like [symfony](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35886859/5742575).

I told you the quick and dirty way above.

I just want to note in the end that I actully don't see any reason of placing your php-logic above your html. Since only your html depends on the php and not the other way around what precise advantage do you promise yourself from placing the html above the php?

One last option: It would be even better if you separated your html and php-code entirely and use include. You would end up with two files:

template.html.php:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <pre id="output"><?= $pre_tag; ?></pre>
</body>
</html>
```

logic.php:

```
$arr = ['apple', 'orange', 'bananas'];

foreach($arr as $value)
{
  $pre_tag.= "$value <br/>\n";
}

include('template.html.php');
```

But the clean and solid solution is to use a MVC-Framework.

Comment: Thx, but this does not work if i place the php code above the <pre> tags. I think it is impossible without generating JavaScript code.
http://www.pasteall.org/66122/php

Comment: You mixed it up! http://www.pasteall.org/66123/php This works placing html below and above. If you just place html below the php code (like you did this time) then you should actually remove all the ob_start(), ob_end(), echo $html stuff and so on. If you don't understand what I mean I will make the edit for you. However this one works as you intend.

Comment: This works, but now if i place the pre tag above the code, then it does not work again. `Undefined variable: loop_result`. So i think it is only possible by generating JavaScript

Comment: no, please refer to my answer. You need to work in different ways depending on whether you want to place the html above or below your code. 1) html about php: use ob_start() 2) php aboub html: inject a variable into the html. If you want it to be mixed then you still need to make use of both options. Would you mind explaining me your motivation for placing the html above the php? If it's because of aesthetics then please stick to my include or framework solution!

Comment: " You need to work in different ways depending on whether you want to place the html above or below your code. "
Yes and that is the problem. I searched for a solution where i don't have to worry about this.

Comment: @EdwardBlack alright, so then stick to the framework solution (sympfony) or work with include-files, then you won't need to bother about placing php above html or below anymore at all. I'd still like to know the reason why you are doing so much efforts. You can solve every problem where you would place the html above the php by placing it below also. JS of course also works, you might also take this approach.